# Object Oriented CSS, BEM, and Expressive

Tags: css, bem

Is using the [BEM](http://getbem.com/) CSS naming methodology considered a form of [Expressive](http://johnpolacek.github.io/expressive-css/) CSS? Are either of them "Object Oriented CSS?"

Answer (score 0):

BEM in general is about component approach for frontend then just for CSS (see https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#how-does-bem-differ-from-oocss-amcss-smacss-suitcss).

But you are right that CSS part of BEM is similar to what OOCSS suggests.